# SQL CASE IF [VALUE] WHEN [Value] AND [VALUE] THEN

Tags: sql, case

I'm not sure if I'm over complicating such a small task but if anyone could help me a little in the right direction then that would be appreciated.

I have two tables which have the same fields, I have created a view with both of these values into one.

As it stands the statement I have is:

```
    SELECT TOP 1000 [Name]
      ,[WorkOrder]
      ,[OnSiteStarted]
      ,[OnSiteSubmitted]

  FROM [DBName].[dbo].[sw_onsite_offsite]
  ORDER BY WorkOrder
```

The result set comes out as (snippet):

```
Name       WorkOrder      OnSiteStarted          OnSiteSubmitted
On-Site     23022017    2017-02-23 20:31:49.000  2017-02-23 20:33:47.000
Off-Site      35        2017-02-15 18:32:26.000  2017-02-15 21:11:04.000
On-Site     64169086    2017-02-22 11:42:40.000  2017-02-22 15:10:17.000
Off-Site    91487689    2017-02-11 13:48:11.000  2017-02-11 14:32:37.000
On-Site     91494707    2017-02-13 14:39:42.000  2017-02-13 14:49:03.000
Off-Site    92810031    2017-02-17 09:30:59.000  2017-02-17 09:58:19.000
On-Site     92810031    2017-02-17 09:00:12.000  2017-02-17 09:30:48.000
Off-Site    92810034    2017-02-17 10:01:27.000  2017-02-17 10:24:45.000
On-Site     92810039    2017-03-03 12:33:41.000  2017-03-03 12:52:37.000
Off-Site    92810039    2017-03-03 12:44:52.000  2017-03-03 13:41:35.000
```

The end result I am after is: When the Off-Site and On-Site form have the same WorkOrder number this will display them only along with the DATEDIFF(MINUTES, [onsitesubmitted], [offsitesubmitted] fields.

Would a CASE statement be applicable in this somehow or would it be something else?

Comment: Can you show us the desired output?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a self join:

```
select t1.WorkOrder,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTES, t1.onsitesubmitted, t2.OnSiteSubmitted) diff
from [DBName].[dbo].[sw_onsite_offsite] t1
join [DBName].[dbo].[sw_onsite_offsite] t2 on t1.WorkOrder = t2.WorkOrder
where t1.name = 'On-Site'
    and t2.name = 'Off-Site'
```

This return only those rows that have same WorkOrder present for both offsite and onsite. You can use appropriate outer join if you want it to produces results even in case of no match.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT onsite.[WorkOrder],
       DATEDIFF(MINUTES, onsite.OnSiteSubmitted, offsite.OnSiteSubmitted)
FROM   [DBName].[dbo].[sw_onsite_offsite] onsite join [DBName].[dbo].[sw_onsite_offsite] offsite on onsite.WorkOrder = offsite.WorkOrder
WHERE  onsite.Name = 'On-Site' AND
       offsite.Name = 'Off-Site'
ORDER BY WorkOrder
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `lead()` or `lag()` window function if your database supports it (you have not tagged a database, but it looks like sql-server)

```
select 
    Name
  , WorkOrder
  , OnSiteStarted
  , OnSiteSubmitted
  , datediff(minute
      , lead([onsitesubmitted]) over (
          partition by WorkOrder 
          order by Name 
        )
      , [onsitesubmitted]
     ) as Duration
from [dbo].[sw_onsite_offsite]
order by WorkOrder, OnSiteSubmitted
```

rextester demo in sql server: http://rextester.com/OTNS68646

returns:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|   Name   | WorkOrder |    OnSiteStarted    |   OnSiteSubmitted   | Duration |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| Off-Site |        35 | 2017-02-15 18:32:26 | 2017-02-15 21:11:04 | NULL     |
| On-Site  |  23022017 | 2017-02-23 20:31:49 | 2017-02-23 20:33:47 | NULL     |
| On-Site  |  64169086 | 2017-02-22 11:42:40 | 2017-02-22 15:10:17 | NULL     |
| Off-Site |  91487689 | 2017-02-11 13:48:11 | 2017-02-11 14:32:37 | NULL     |
| On-Site  |  91494707 | 2017-02-13 14:39:42 | 2017-02-13 14:49:03 | NULL     |
| On-Site  |  92810031 | 2017-02-17 09:00:12 | 2017-02-17 09:30:48 | NULL     |
| Off-Site |  92810031 | 2017-02-17 09:30:59 | 2017-02-17 09:58:19 | 28       |
| Off-Site |  92810034 | 2017-02-17 10:01:27 | 2017-02-17 10:24:45 | NULL     |
| On-Site  |  92810039 | 2017-03-03 12:33:41 | 2017-03-03 12:52:37 | NULL     |
| Off-Site |  92810039 | 2017-03-03 12:44:52 | 2017-03-03 13:41:35 | 49       |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```